# Resolve a promise if a function is executed 5 times

Tags: javascript

I'm confused about why my promise doesn't work and how to fix it. Here is it:

```js
let loadedNum = 0;
function loaded(){

   loadedNum++
   console.log(loadedNum);
 
  return new Promise((resolve) => {  
 
  if(loadedNum >= 5){
     
     console.log('Entered if statment and should resolve the promise')
     resolve(); 
  } 
 
  }); 
}

async function int(){
  await loaded();
  loadedNum = 0;
  console.log('Promise Resolved Successfully!')
}

setTimeout(() => loaded(), 2000);
setTimeout(() => loaded(), 4000);
setTimeout(() => loaded(), 5000);
setTimeout(() => loaded(), 6000);
setTimeout(() => loaded(), 7000);
setTimeout(() => int(), 3000);
```

The logic is I want to resolve the promise after the `loaded()` function is executed **5** times.

Otherwise, it should wait. no matter when `int` function is executed...

**Note:** the confusing part is even if my code enters in if statement it doesn't resolve the promise!?

**Note 2:** Even more confusion... the code works here but it doesn't work in chrome console and also jsfiddle?????

Comment: Every call to `loaded()` returns its own Promise. Only the last one will ever be resolved.

Comment: Please look at Note 2 in the question...

Comment: Well then what is the problem? There's really nothing special about this environment; this code, exactly as posted, should work. I just pasted it into a file and ran it with Node and it worked.

Comment: paste the code on chrome console and you never see the `console.log('Promise Resolved Successfully!')`

Comment: I see "Promise Resolved Successfully!" in my Chrome console.

Comment: Can you please tell us what version do you use?

Comment: Version 81.0.4044.138

Comment: I have updated the code please guys help me to solve this...

Comment: int() never resolves, because the if statement returns false after 3 seconds.  It doesn't "wait" for loadedNum to change.  int() would have to be called on an interval to check if loadedNum is above 5.  Although I don't really see why you aren't just using int() for all the calls based on your "requirements".  Honestly your use case here doesn't really even fit promises, but events.

Comment: @ user120242 I got it to know... thanks ... so you recommend to use an interval instead... can you please prepare an answer...

Comment: move the promise to a variable declared in a scope above `loaded` like `loadedNum`. Then `await` that promise.

Comment: @ Aluan Haddad would you please prepare an answer... I can't make your solution work...

Answer (score 1):

*int()'s call to loaded() never resolves, because the if statement (loadedNum>=5) returns false right after 3 seconds when it is called (loadedNum is 1 at that point). It doesn't "wait" for loadedNum to change to >= 5.*

Below code exposes a global Promise's resolver that is called whenever loaded() sees that loadedNum >= 5.

This change allows the code to behave the way you have asked, but you should clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve and what problem you are actually solving, as this is probably not the best solution.

```js
let loadedNum = 0;
let resolver;
let p = new Promise(r=>resolver=r);
function loaded(){
   loadedNum++
   console.log(loadedNum);
 
  if(loadedNum >= 5){
     console.log('Entered if statment and should resolve the promise')
     resolver(); 
  } 
  return p;
}

async function int(){
  await loaded();
  loadedNum = 0;
  p = new Promise(r=>resolver=r);
  console.log('Promise Resolved Successfully!')
}

setTimeout(() => loaded(), 2000);
setTimeout(() => loaded(), 4000);
setTimeout(() => loaded(), 5000);
setTimeout(() => loaded(), 6000);
setTimeout(() => loaded(), 7000);
setTimeout(() => int(), 3000);
setTimeout(() => loaded(), 8000);
setTimeout(() => loaded(), 9000);
setTimeout(() => loaded(), 9000);
setTimeout(() => loaded(), 9000);
setTimeout(() => loaded(), 9000);
setTimeout(() => int(), 10000);
```